# MYSQL count a specific entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "Top-20" System in my Webinterface where 20 players got listed and sorted by level. Now i want to show the guy, who is logged in, at the bottom of the table and display which entry he is.
I have made it with photoshop to show how it should be:

[image]

My question is, how can i get the number of this specific entry?
For the top 20 i have following query:

```
select username,spielerlevel,member,leader 
from accounts 
where adminlevel = 0 
order by spielerlevel desc 
limit 20
```

Thanks.

Comment: to get answer of this you first show your table structure

Comment: Why is player 4 for instance listed lower than player 3?

Comment: @Strawberry I have just editet my query. The new one looks like this: "...order by spielerlevel desc, connectedTime desc limit 20"

Comment: Assuming `spielerlevel` and `level` are the same thing, my question still stands.

Comment: @Strawberry spielerlevel and connectetTime, not spielerlevel and level. connectedTime = Time in hours how long a player was ingame

Comment: @mathi1993 You've lost me, but it seems like others are able to help.

Answer (score 4):

An approximation of his place in the list is given by this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM accounts
WHERE adminlevel = 0 
  AND spielerlevel<[level]
```

(Replace `[level]` with the respective user's level.)

The problem is just with many user having the same level. But this might be a problem in your example query as well.

Comment: Clever! I was going to suggest using temporary tables. I don't know why you claim it's an approximation, it should return an exact and accurate match.

Comment: @Dai The problem exists, when the levels are not distinct. Suppose 5 players all with the same level. According the the given query they might get ranks 11-15. But my query will always return a count of 10 for all of them. That's why I call it an approximation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yeah, you are right. This is a problem, because I have "226,443" accounts in my table. :D
Can't I do it with "select username,spielerlevel,member,leader from accounts where adminlevel = 0 AND username = 'Username' order by spielerlevel desc limit 20" and give this entry the number somehow?

Comment: @user2485108 Don't you have something like a value "experience" or something, which would (most of the time) avoid these ordering problems?

Comment: @user2485108 You could try it with something like this rank shim: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333665/1169798

Comment: @Sirko I have a value called "spielstunden", but the problem is, if guys registers, they have 0 ingame hours, so I can't take this too...hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1
FROM accounts
WHERE adminlevel = 0
AND spierlerlevel < (
    SELECT spierlerlevel 
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE username = "CURRENT USER NAME"
);
```